# Is it possible to add a login page before Swagger ui?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor, swagger-node-express

I need to add a separate login page before Swagger UI for authentication from another server. From this request I will get a key which I have to add in the header of every req from swagger UI.

I'm using a node server and swagger-tool with swagger 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using nginx you could add basic HTTP Authentication. Then anytime anyone goes to your docs url or sub-domain they'll get a pop-up user/password dialog before being able to access swagger-ui.

[Full instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) for creating your user/password combinations (assuming Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd exampleuser
```

The tool will prompt you for a password.

Then update your nginx file to have something like this for the docs route:

```
location /docs {
   auth_basic "Restricted Content";
   auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
   proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;
 }
```

Then reload nginx:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```